# How to get ClientSecretCredential expiration using azure python sdk?

Tags: azure

I am trying to get credential token expiration

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential

token_credential = ClientSecretCredential()

from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=oauth, credential=token_credential)
```

It seems like the token is encapsulate in `ClientSecretCredential` but there is no public api to get, is there a way i can see the expiration of the token?

Comment: Why do you want to get the token expiration?

Comment: I am trying to understand how token expiration work, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes says 60min expiration, but the token never expires after 60 min

Comment: This is because the SDK takes care of renewal of token for you so that you need not worry about renewing the token when it expires. If you track the request/response to Azure Storage, you will notice a different bearer token is used after every 60 minutes.

Comment: I see, so if I have a large file that takes more than 60 minute to download or upload, thats when the token expiration kicks in?

Comment: That is correct.